# How can I animate the font size of Text from .largeTitle to .headline

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a Text that I want to decrease the font size when it appears, from a `.largeTitle to .headline`

**Here is what I am trying so far (which doesn't work):**

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var fontSize: CGFloat = 100

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Text("Big Text - Small Text")
                .font(.system(size: self.fontSize))
                .onAppear {
                    withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 10)) {
                        // what do I do here?
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Font size is not animatable by default. The below solution is based on custom animatable modifier.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct AnimatingFontSize: AnimatableModifier {
    var fontSize: CGFloat

    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { fontSize }
        set { fontSize = newValue }
    }

    func body(content: Self.Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(.system(size: self.fontSize))
    }
}

struct DemoFontView: View {
    @State private var smallFont = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Big Text - Small Text")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .modifier(AnimatingFontSize(fontSize: smallFont ? 11 : 100))
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 10), value: smallFont)
            .onAppear {
                smallFont = true
            }
    }
}
```